# jdbc - no rows in resultset error

Tags: java, sql-server, jsp, jdbc

I am trying to display results in descending order in for a positions and first name of the winner.

Here is my code in a jsp file

```
    try 
    {
    // Get Connection
    Connection connection = SQLServer.getSQLServerConnection();

    // Create statement
    Statement statement = connection.createStatement();

    String sql = " select    distinct   PositionTitle, max(NumberOFCount) as  votes From votecount  Group By  PositionTitle order by  votes desc";
    //Execute SQL statement returns a ResultSet object.
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(sql);
    List<String> position =new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> count =new ArrayList<>();


    int i = 0;
    while(rs.next() && i<6){


         position.add(i, rs.getString(1));
         count.add(i, rs.getString(2));
         i++;
    } 

    rs.close();

    String[] pstn = (String[]) position.toArray(new String[position.size()]);
    String[] cnt = (String[]) count.toArray(new String[count.size()]);


         /* Iterator<String> postn = position.iterator();
         Iterator<String> cnt = count.iterator(); */

        for(int j=0;j<6;j++)
         {

          String sql1 = " Select FirstName from votecount where PositionTitle ='"+pstn[j]+"' and NumberOFCount = '"+cnt[j]+"'";
         ResultSet rs1 = statement.executeQuery(sql1);

             String FirstName = rs1.getString(0);

        %>
        <p align="center"><%=pstn[j] %> : <%=FirstName %>  </p>
        <p></p>

<%      


         }
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace (response.getWriter());
}%>
```

I am getting

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The result set has no current row. at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDriverError(SQLServerException.java:189) error

When I debug and execute the same query in my database it does show results.

What could be the possible mistake that I made? I have tried debugging it many times.

Comment: There are two sql quires in the code, which is causing the Exception?  Also can you show the exact query that works in your database?

Comment: As suggested by @happymeal, you may simply need to invoke `rs1.next()` like you did for `rs`. OracleDocs can answer as to the [why](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) (2nd line).